# Custom Footer on Each Included PDF

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr, pdfpages

I'm working on a document that's essentially a collection of PDFs (about 55).

Here's what I've got so far:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[letterpaper,margin=1in,landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{pdfpages, tocloft, fancyhdr, xcolor, helvet, bookmark}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

\renewcommand\numberline[1]{}
\renewcommand{\cftsecpagefont}{\color{white}} %Hack to hide section page numbers

\renewcommand{\cftsecfont}{\color{tbsteal} \bfseries \Large}% Section colour
\definecolor{myteal}{RGB}{0, 128, 128}

\pagestyle{fancy} 
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyfoot[LE,LO]{\thepage}

\begin{document}
\newgeometry{margin=1.5cm}
\pdfbookmark[section]{\contentsname}{toc}
\tableofcontents
\restoregeometry
\newpage

%Tab 1
\includepdf[pages=-, pagecommand={}, addtotoc={1, section, 1, Key Context, Key Context, 1, subsection, 2, My, Labour Relations Primer}]{MyCoolPDFDocument1.pdf}
\includepdf[pages=-, pagecommand={}]{MyAwesomePDFDocument.pdf}
...
...
```

I essentially want to put a custom footer on the bottom right of every included pdf. As far as I'm aware PDFPages utilize the default page style throughout and the page numbers at the bottom left. The only other option I've heard of is to define custom page styles for every document. Which gets a bit unsustainable.

Love some input here.

Comment: and what is the content of the footers?

Comment: I'm looking to put some custom text on the right side, so included PDF would be:
`page number                                                      tab 1.1`

Comment: You could use the `pagecommand` option for each included pdf : `pagecommand={\fancyfoot[R]{custom text}}`.

Comment: Edit that works! So simple...I'm annoyed it took me so long! Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages, fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\lfoot{\thepage}
\cfoot{\rightmark}

\begin{document}
\includepdf[pages=-, pagecommand={\markright{my cool document}}]{example-image-a4-numbered}
\includepdf[pages=-, pagecommand={\markright{my second cool document}}]{example-image-a4-numbered}
\end{document}
```

[image]